# Is it possible to die before your town has started?

Tags: die2nite

I joined a random town, which presently has 28 of 40 citizens. The game said the town will not start until there are 40 citizens.

Does this mean I won't be killed at night or die from thirst while the town hasn't started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean I won't be killed at night or die from thirst while the town hasn't started?

Yes. Night won't fall on your city until you have 40 citizens. (You'll still get the planned downtime every day, however.) This also means that your AP do *not* regenerate, as the day isn't yet over.

Comment: Some of us participated in a town where day 1 lasted about a week (the very first town for people with 100+ soul points)

Comment: I remember that @bwarner.  Because of this extended first day, we got some *serious* plans laid, and went on to be the top scoring town for quite some time.